# jquery Animate Number reanimate on screen enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a mix of [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs) and [animate number.js](https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber) to create a mini quiz. Based on values selected throughout the slides, a final slide has a cost estimate.

When a user enters the final slide, the numbers will animate through 0 - 10000 and 0 - 15000. However, when a user leaves the slide and maybe changes what they want, the cost may increase, but the last slide the numbers will not reanimate. I've tried setting the values to 0 when a user leaves the final slide, but this doesn't work if the animate animation is still running, and if it does work, the animation doesn't run again on enter of the slide.

```
<div class="segment_quiz_question">
    <div>£<span class="priceRange11">15,000</span> - £<span class="priceRange12">20,000</span></div>
    <div>£<span class="priceRange11">20,000</span> - £<span class="priceRange12">25,000</span></div>
</div>




$('.segment_quiz_questions').fullpage({
        sectionSelector: '.segment_quiz_question',
        verticalCentered: false,

        onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
        if (index == $('.segment_quiz_question').length) {
                $('.priceRange11').text("0");
                $('.priceRange12').text("0");
                $('.priceRange21').text("0");
                $('.priceRange22').text("0");
            };

            var comma_separator_number_step = $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.separator(',')
            if (nextIndex == $('.segment_quiz_question').length) {
                $('.priceRange11').animateNumber({
                    number: 15000,                            
                    numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
                    }, 2000
                );
                $('.priceRange12').animateNumber({
                    number: 20000,
                    numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
                }, 3000
                );
                $('.priceRange21').animateNumber({
                    number: 20000,
                    numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
                }, 2000
                );
                $('.priceRange22').animateNumber({
                    number: 25000,
                    numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
                }, 3000
                );
           }
      }
});
```

I basically want the numbers to always animate from 0 - their value on enter of the final slide.

Comment: Maybe a JsFiddle? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix it myself, using `.prop("number", "0")`.

I removed the entire `$('.priceRange11').text("0");` section of the script and added the `.prop("number", "0")` to the rest like so:

```
$('.priceRange11').prop("number", "0").animateNumber({
    number: 15000,                            
    numberStep: comma_separator_number_step
    }, 2000
);
```